# Вывод параметризованных запросов

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть запрос, который выводит фамилии и номера заказов:

```
declare @fam varchar(30)  , @order int   
select    Table.fam , Table.idOrder  
from Table  
where 
Table.fam = @fam  or  Table.idOrder = @order
```

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы в параметре запроса можно было выбрать: вывод всех данных/данных по параметру?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для игнорирования параметров можно использовать `IsNull`:

```
where Table.fam = isnull(@fam,Table.fam)  or  Table.idOrder = isnull(@order,Table.idOrder)
```

Ну и, соответственно, передавать `null` в качестве значения параметра, когда его нужно игнорировать.

Comment: Спасибо. именно то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода всех данных добавьте условие

```
or 1=1
```

в предложение WHERE.